# Where are the shortcuts for the Windows 7 Taskbar stored on disk?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Where, in the Windows 7 file system, are the taskbar shortcuts stored (per user)?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Taskbar shortcuts are located in: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`.

You can also add the "Quick Launch" folder to your task bar as a toolbar to re-enable the quick launch feature.

Comment: Yes. Can anyone explain why they're in an "Internet Explorer" folder?

Comment: Hint: sometimes you place links to apps here and they do not appear on your taskbar. This is probably because your app is on a network drive. Only local apps are working.

Comment: More specifically, look under: AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Answer (score 37):

Hit the Windows key and paste

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

to find the pinned taskbar items, or simply

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\
```

to see the folders for those and the start menu items.

If you're having trouble getting Windows to remember pinned items you may need to remove the Favorites registry key at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like Quick Launch, you can create your own with "New toolbar", which can be anywhere; it's a folder. The toolbar name is the folder name.

I put it under the hidden folder `C:\ProgramData` so it will be easily accessible to all users. But it can go wherever you like.

Comment: How do you get to "new toolbar"?

Comment: @ragerdl, right click the task bar and open the 'toolbars' sub menu.

Comment: where this setting is stored? I need to find it to check why windows keep forgetting my new toolbar

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned`.

Comment: That answer has already been given a couple times.

Comment: @music2myear Please look at the answer in detail. It's different path than others thats why I added a new one.

Comment: Your issue was different if this "solved" your problems. %AppData% IS the user profile AppData folder for the active session's user.

Comment: at least the addition of **%USERPROFILE%** makes it different from the others thus making it easily understandable

Comment: @music2myear you really don't understand what's different in detail. None of the other answers has specified `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` path

Answer (score 0):

The folder is in this location , windows 7 Ultimate.
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Hope to help you !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).